# Shifting columns in a row-major matrix

Tags: cuda

Given the **fat** matrix `A=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]`, I am trying to shift (permute) rows, i.e. `B=[[11,12,13,14,15],[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]`, and shift columns, i.e. `C=[[5,1,2,3,4],[10,6,7,8,9],[15,11,12,13,14]]`

I made a similar kernel as shifting columns:

```
// A->C
__global__ void column_shift(int* mat, int row, int col) {
    int row_num = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (row_num < row) {
        int a = mat[row_num * col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col - 1; ++i) {
            mat[row_num * col + i] = mat[row_num * col + i + 1];
        }
        mat[row_num * col + (col - 1)] = a;
    }
}

// A->B
__global__ void row_shift(int* mat, int row, int col) {
    int col_num = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (col_num < col) {
        int a = mat[(row - 1) * col + col_num];
        for (int i = row - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            mat[i * col + col_num] = mat[(i - 1) * col + col_num];
        }
        mat[col_num] = a;
    }
}
```

However, comparing to `row_shift`, `column_shift` performs worse. I guess this is due to memory coalescing. Are there efficient way to enhance performance of `column_shift`?

Comment: In column shift kernel, not a single memory operation you do is coalesced. The performance is bad because of that. If your rows are short enough, you can try reading a block of data(multiple rows) to shared memory, shift the columns and write it back to global memory. However, this might use less or more memory transactions depending on how long your rows are and how many columns you are shifting.

Comment: I also don't think either kernel actually does the operations you describe in the text

Comment: @talonmies sorry, I put the wrong code. I changed it.

Comment: @AkifÇördük You mean row_shift right? But since read and write for global memory occurs once per each element in the column, would caching in shared memory help?

Comment: The column shift operation example in your question appears to swap the first and last row entries. The code doesn't do that

Comment: @Square -- I also don't understand your question regarding the performance of `row_shift`. In my benchmarking, `column_shift` is about 10 times slower than `row_shift` because of the lack of memory coalescing.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for pointing that out. I've wrote wrong example and doing something wrong with the code; I think I resolved all the errors. I've changed my question, and are there anyway to overcome memory coalescing problem in `column_shift`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious performance issue with `column_shift` is a lack of memory coalescing. This could be fixed by have a warp of threads perform the row data shift, rather than a single thread.

Consider the following example (note I have rewritten your kernels to use a simple helper class which both simplifies the kernel code, and reduces the risk of indexing calculation errors (as was the case in at least one of the kernels you originally posted):

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <vector>

struct stride2D
{
   int* p;
   int s0;
   __host__ __device__
   stride2D(int* _p, int _s0) : p(_p), s0(_s0) {};
   __host__ __device__
   int operator  () (int x, int y) const { return p[x*s0 + y]; };
   __host__ __device__
   int& operator () (int x, int y) { return p[x*s0 + y]; };
};

__global__ void column_shift2(int* mat, int row, int col)
{
    int row_num = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    stride2D m(mat, col);   

    if (row_num < row) {
        int a = m(row_num, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < col-1; i++) {
            m(row_num, i) = m(row_num, i+1);
        }
        m(row_num, col-1) = a;
    }
}

__global__ void column_shift3(int* mat, int row, int col)
{
    int row_num = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    stride2D m(mat, col);   
    if (row_num < row) {
        int a = m(row_num, 0);
        for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < col-1; i += warpSize) {
            m(row_num, i) = m(row_num, i+1);
        }
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) m(row_num, col-1) = a;
    }
}

__global__ void row_shift2(int* mat, int row, int col) {
    int col_num = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    stride2D m(mat, col);   
    if (col_num < col) {
        int a = m(row-1, col_num);
        for (int i = row - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            m(i, col_num) = m(i-1, col_num);
        }
        m(0, col_num) = a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int r = 300, c = 900, n = r * c;

    {
        std::vector<int> idata(n);
        thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(1);
        thrust::copy(first, first+n, idata.begin());

        thrust::device_vector<int> ddata(idata);
        int* d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ddata.data());

        int bsize = 256, nblocks = (c / bsize) + (c % bsize > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        row_shift2<<<nblocks, bsize>>>(d, r, c);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        std::vector<int> odata(n);
        thrust::copy(ddata.begin(), ddata.end(), odata.begin());
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> idata(n);
        thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(1);
        thrust::copy(first, first+n, idata.begin());

        thrust::device_vector<int> ddata(idata);
        int* d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ddata.data());

        int bsize = 256, nblocks = (r / bsize) + (r % bsize > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        column_shift2<<<nblocks, bsize>>>(d, r, c);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        std::vector<int> odata(n);
        thrust::copy(ddata.begin(), ddata.end(), odata.begin());
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> idata(n);
        thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(1);
        thrust::copy(first, first+n, idata.begin());

        thrust::device_vector<int> ddata(idata);
        int* d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(ddata.data());

        const int bwidth = 32;
        dim3 bsize(bwidth, 1024/bwidth);
        int nblocks = (r / bsize.y) + (r % bsize.y > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        column_shift3<<<nblocks, bsize>>>(d, r, c);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        std::vector<int> odata(n);
        thrust::copy(ddata.begin(), ddata.end(), odata.begin());
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

The only real change required is the inner copying loop within the `column_shift` operation:

```
    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < col-1; i += warpSize) {
        m(row_num, i) = m(row_num, i+1);
    }
```

Now we use a warp strided loop (which must be run with `blockDim.x = 32` for correctness). Profiling this code shows this:

```
nvprof ./permute
==13687== NVPROF is profiling process 13687, command: ./permute
==13687== Profiling application: ./permute
==13687== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   51.24%  643.80us         1  643.80us  643.80us  643.80us  column_shift2(int*, int, int)
                   21.36%  268.41us         3  89.471us  89.087us  89.887us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                   21.06%  264.57us         3  88.191us  87.647us  89.023us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                    5.54%  69.631us         1  69.631us  69.631us  69.631us  row_shift2(int*, int, int)
                    0.81%  10.144us         1  10.144us  10.144us  10.144us  column_shift3(int*, int, int)
      API calls:   68.19%  114.44ms         3  38.148ms  78.552us  114.28ms  cudaMalloc
                   30.00%  50.352ms         1  50.352ms  50.352ms  50.352ms  cudaDeviceReset
                    0.65%  1.0974ms         6  182.89us  102.55us  246.46us  cudaMemcpyAsync
                    0.44%  732.75us         3  244.25us  13.565us  646.95us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.21%  348.53us        97  3.5930us     263ns  197.14us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.17%  290.47us         1  290.47us  290.47us  290.47us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.16%  266.04us         6  44.339us  2.3170us  87.602us  cudaStreamSynchronize
                    0.11%  184.85us         3  61.616us  53.903us  71.672us  cudaFree
                    0.03%  54.650us         3  18.216us  13.862us  25.133us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.03%  51.108us         1  51.108us  51.108us  51.108us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%  4.0760us         3  1.3580us     408ns  3.1910us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  3.4620us         1  3.4620us  3.4620us  3.4620us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  1.6850us         2     842ns     248ns  1.4370us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     585ns         1     585ns     585ns     585ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
```

i.e. the warp strided copy is about 60 times faster than your original implementation.

[Note all code *extremely* lightly tested, and no guarantees of correctness or optimality are made or implied]